# pandas html fucntion converting into to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a df and I am converting it into HTML to send as an email attachment.

Email function:-

```
def send_email(text,html,me,you):
    #me = "test@gmail.com"
    #you = "test@test.com"

    # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "Link"
    msg['From'] = me
    msg['To'] = you

    # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    # Attach parts into message container.
    # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
    # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

    # Send the message via local SMTP server.
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    # sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
    # and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
    s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
```

After that, I am converting my DF to HTML:-

```
text = "below is the data"
html = df.to_html()
```

It's converting all the numeric fields to float. How I can avoid that?

Comment: What types do your numeric fields have in the dataframe?

Comment: it's in interger format

Comment: Which of the integer types? Can you please [edit] the post with the output of `df.dtypes`? See also: providing a [mcve]: Your question does not contain the information necessary to reproduce the problem. Neither does it show what the problem actually is (i.e. the bad HTML output), by the way.